# Invalid Parameter ImageMagick (Windows 10)

Tags: imagemagick, graphic

I am trying to generate an image that is 1px wide and 100px tall of a gradient, which goes from white to #3532CB, and then save it in my directory as topgrad1.png
After changing the directory to the image folder in cmd.exe, I entered:

```
    convert -size 1x100 gradient:white-#3532cb topgrad1.png
```

When entered, it gives the result of: Invalid Parameter - 1x100

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

That error indicates you're accessing a Windows command "convert.exe", probably in the "C:\Windows\System32\directory". You need to make sure your ImageMagick's "convert" command is in your PATH, or call your IM "convert" with the full path. Or if you're using IM7, you should be using "magick" instead of "convert" anyway, and still make sure it's in your PATH.

Comment: I suspect that GeeMack's answer is the correct one for Windows users rather than mine below.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick, at least on Unix systems, you need to quote your colors, especially if using hex or rgb(...) colors. So

```
convert -size 1x100 gradient:"white-#3532cb" topgrad1.png
```

[image]